# Как найти пользователей с одинаковыми свойствами?

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток товарищи! У меня проблемка с поиском дубликатов так сказать. Для примера быстренько сделал для вас пару таблиц, мне нужно найти разных пользователей (их `id` естественно уникальны), у которых совпадают свойства.

К примеру у пользователей 1 и 3 (таблица `user`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

совпадают свойства **русый** и **высокий** (таблица `user_property`):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мне и нужны на выходе `user_id` 1 и 3. Совпадение должно быть точь в точь, ну т.е. 2 свойства = 2 свойства (порядок не важен), чтобы не было 3-го, которое просто как бы лишнее, как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал разные способы, но что-то я слабоват видимо в `mysql` и в 1 запрос никак не получается данные получить, может вы сможете подсказать как лучше и желательно в 1 запрос всё это реализовать.

P.S. `join` как и таблицу `user` в принципе использовать не обязательно, главное, в данном примере получить `user_id`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9e44db)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант

```
SELECT
  p1.user_id,
  p2.user_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(p1.property_name),
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
  user_property p1
  JOIN user_property p2 ON (
    p1.user_id <> p2.user_id AND
    p1.property_name = p2.property_name
  )
GROUP BY
  p1.user_id,
  p2.user_id
HAVING
  cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_property p3 WHERE p3.user_id = p1.user_id) AND
  cnt = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_property p4 WHERE p4.user_id = p1.user_id)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6721/8)

Ну и само собой разумеется, поля `user_id` и `property_name` должны быть проиндексированы

Еще есть такой вариант

```
SELECT
  p1.user_id,
  p2.user_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p1.property_name ORDER BY p1.property_name) AS `gr`
FROM
  user_property p1
  JOIN user_property p2 ON (
    p1.user_id <> p2.user_id
  )
GROUP BY
  p1.user_id,
  p2.user_id
HAVING
  gr = GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p2.property_name ORDER BY p2.property_name)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6721/11)

Comment: Попробовал ваш пример на своей базе, очень долго выполняется. Я добавил картинку в описании вопроса (картинка №3), можно как-то такой результат получить? главное по совпадений вывести `id` пользователей

Comment: @RifmaMan поля `user_id` и `property_name` должны быть проинднксированы

Comment: @RifmaMan добавил вывод значений

Comment: У меня в базе 750к строк, и оба запроса просто не могут до конца выполниться, вчера просто в течении рабочего дня он так  и не завершился... такой вариант мне не подходит? =( Я тем временем пробую различные варианты с GROUP_CONCAT, вкладываю запрос в запрос, вроде немного есть прогресс, однако не тот результат, который хотел получить...

Comment: Вы индексы посоздавали? Первый запрос, при индексах на `user_id` и `property_name` должен выполняться оперативно

Comment: Да, конечно, они были созданы, только это в примере `user_id` и `property_name` у меня другие поля, но они и были индексными...

Comment: @RifmaMan при таком объеме записей `property_name` должно быть числовым и быть ссылкой на отдельную таблицу свойств. Как я понимаю, свойств у вас не больше сотни?

Comment: Всё верно, эта таблица с указанием связей, где `user_id` и `property_name` числовые, ну а свойств может быть большое количество, к примеру в той таблице из ~100k

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать что-то такое ([подробнее](//stackoverflow.com/a/276949/4928642)):

```
SELECT user_id
FROM user_property
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING GROUP_CONCAT(property_name ORDER BY property_name ASC SEPARATOR ',') = N'высокий,русый'
```

Но боюсь, что такое будет довольно медленно работать...

Comment: мне кажется, значения свойств не известны по условию

Comment: а если известны, то выборку по свойствам, и count=2

Comment: @teran, но ведь собрать значения свойств в строку не проблема?

Comment: @teran, теоретически можно попытаться даже сделать `join on GROUP_CONCAT(...) = GROUP_CONCAT(...)`?